# Dockerfileから、centos7のサービスを起動したい

Tags: vagrant, centos, docker

お世話になります

先日Dockerで質問させてもらったばかりなのですが、また質問させてください
先日試したことを、今度はcentos7のDockerで試してみたく、トライしてるのですが、サービスをうまく起動させることができず、苦戦しております

```
[shiratsu@localhost centos7]$ cat Dockerfile
# SSH-DOCKER
#
# VERSION       1

FROM centos

MAINTAINER shiratsu

RUN yum swap -y -- remove fakesystemd -- install systemd systemd-libs && yum clean all
RUN yum -y update && yum clean all

#Dev tools for all Docker
RUN yum -y install git vim

RUN yum -y install passwd openssh openssh-server openssh-clients sudo


# create user

RUN useradd shiratsu
RUN passwd -f -u shiratsu
RUN mkdir -p /home/shiratsu/.ssh;chown shiratsu /home/shiratsu/.ssh; chmod 700 /home/shiratsu/.ssh
ADD ./authorized_keys /home/shiratsu/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN chown shiratsu /home/shiratsu/.ssh/authorized_keys;chmod 600 /home/shiratsu/.ssh/authorized_keys

# setup sudoers
RUN echo "shiratsu ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/shiratsu

# setup sshd
#ADD systemctl /usr/bin/systemctl
#ADD dbus.service /etc/systemd/system/dbus.service
#RUN ln -sf dbus.service /etc/systemd/system/messagebus.service

ADD ./sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN /usr/bin/systemctl enable sshd.service;/usr/bin/systemctl start    sshd.service;/usr/bin/systemctl stop sshd.service

# expose for sshd
EXPOSE 2222

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd","-D"]
```

カーネルのアップデートをしないとsysコマンドは実行できないようですので、アップデートをしようとしてるのですが、うまくいかず、ハマっております
http://qiita.com/zkangaroo/items/a3e1cd4b4d28a7c12e14

最後のmake module_install installでこけてしまいます
http://www.tecmint.com/kernel-3-5-released-install-compile-in-redhat-centos-and-fedora/

```
INSTALL /lib/firmware/kaweth/trigger_code_fix.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/ti_3410.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/ti_5052.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/mts_cdma.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/mts_gsm.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/mts_edge.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/edgeport/boot.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/edgeport/boot2.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/edgeport/down.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/edgeport/down2.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/edgeport/down3.bin
INSTALL /lib/firmware/whiteheat_loader.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/whiteheat.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/keyspan_pda/keyspan_pda.fw
INSTALL /lib/firmware/keyspan_pda/xircom_pgs.fw
DEPMOD  3.5.0
/usr/src/linux-3.5/scripts/depmod.sh: line 37:  7557 強制終了            "$DEPMOD"   "$@" "$KERNELRELEASE"
make: *** [_modinst_post] エラー 137
```

他にも、それっぽいの試してるのですが、うまくいかず、どこをどうしたらよいのやらという感じです
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ホストOSはCentOS6系でしょうか。[CentOS 7のDockerコンテナ内でsystemdを使ってサービスを起動する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/yunano/items/9637ee21a71eba197345)によると、systemdがカーネルバージョン 3.xを要求するため、ホストOSのカーネルバージョンを上げる必要があるそうです。

Comment: なるほどです！そこまで読み取れてなかったです。ありがとうございます
試してみます

Comment: カーネルのアップデートでハマってしまっております
どなたかご存知ないですか。。。質問に追記します

Comment: カーネルアップデートの問題、どんな問題でしょうか

Comment: centos6.5上にcentos7のdockerを入れて、その中で何かしらのserviceを立ち上げたいのですが、ホストOSのlinuxのカーネルを3にあげないと、ダメみたいでして、あげようとトライしてるのですが、うまくいかずに止まっております。質問に追記してあります

Comment: 参考にされてる情報のコメントに、同様の症状で物理メモリ不足を怪しむ声があるので、プアな仮想環境などの場合はつらいのかもしれません。。

Comment: なるほど。。。やっぱりそういうことですか。。。了解です

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vagrant をお使いだったと思うので CoreOS を入れてやると割と楽に実現できます。

- vagrant に CoreOS を導入

  ```
  $ git clone https://github.com/coreos/coreos-vagrant.git       
  $ cd coreos-vagrant 
  $ vagrant up
  ...
  ```
- CoreOS に入って CentOS 7 を systemd 付きで導入

  ```
  $ vagrant ssh
  Last login: Thu Xxx xx xx:xx:xx xxxx from xx.xx.xx.xx
  CoreOS alpha (561.0.0)
  core@core-01 ~ $ mkdir centos7_systemd
  core@core-01 ~ $ cd centos7_systemd
  core@core-01 ~ $ vi Dockerfile
  core@core-01 ~ $ sudo docker build -t centos7_systemd .
  ...
  ```

  - Dockerfile

    ```
    FROM centos:centos7

    RUN yum swap -y fakesystemd systemd initscripts
    CMD ["/sbin/init", "3"]
    ```
- 起動して nsenter で侵入(動作を見るので port 22 -> 10022 をかけておく)

  ```
  core@core-01 ~ $ sudo docker run --privileged -d -p 10022:22 --name test_name centos7_systemd
  core@core-01 ~ $ sudo nsenter --target $(sudo docker inspect --format '{{.State.Pid}}' test_name) --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
  ```
- コンテナ内でいろいろ段取りする

  ```
  [root@93a9849d14ba /]# yum install -y openssh-server
  ...
  [root@93a9849d14ba /]# echo 'root:changeit' | chpasswd
  [root@93a9849d14ba /]# sed -ri 's/^#PermitRootLogin\s+.*/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
  [root@93a9849d14ba /]# systemctl enable sshd
  [root@93a9849d14ba /]# systemctl start sshd
  [root@93a9849d14ba /]# exit
  ```
- CoreOS から ssh してみる。

  ```
  core@core-01 ~ $ ssh root@localhost -p 10022
  ```

Comment: 試してみます！ありがとうございます。

Comment: カーネルのアップデートでハマってしまっております
どなたかご存知ないですか。。。追記します