# Dockerfileでのsystemctl実行方法について

Tags: docker, docker-compose, systemd

#### 困っていること

`docker-compose up -d` でnginxを起動、自動起動化まで自動で実施してくれるようにしたいと考えて試行錯誤していますが、うまく動作してくれません。
Dockerfileの"RUN systemctl start nginx"の行でエラーが出力されてしまいます。

```
Building nginx
Step 1 : FROM centos:centos7
 ---> 67591570dd29
Step 2 : MAINTAINER nginx
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c36597f0415d
Step 3 : RUN yum -y install epel-release;
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6708fdc2009f
Step 4 : RUN yum -y install nginx
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 15b951c70751
Step 5 : RUN cp -p /usr/share/zoneinfo/Japan /etc/localtime
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 52a75e8f3f4a
Step 6 : COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2b78c951f9f3
Step 7 : RUN systemctl start nginx
 ---> Running in 93eae267d64c
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
ERROR: Service 'nginx' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c systemctl start nginx' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

"RUN systemctl start nginx"を省いた状態では、正常に動作してくれます。
（後ほどdocker execでコンテナに入り、"systemctl start nginx"する必要はあります）

#### 期待する状態

`docker compose up -d` でnginxの起動まで自動化するにはどのように記述すればよろしいのでしょうか。お手数ですがご教示をお願いいたします。（参考URLを貼って頂くだけでも構いません）

※尚、下記URLに記載の内容とほぼ同じ内容なのですが、下記URLでは"カーネルのアップデートが実施できない"ということがメインですので改めて質問させていただきました。
[Dockerfileから、centos7のサービスを起動したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5544/dockerfile%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-centos7%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%93%E3%82%B9%E3%82%92%E8%B5%B7%E5%8B%95%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

#### 環境とファイルの記述

■環境

```
[root@gab docker]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
[root@gab docker]# uname -r
3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64
```

■docker-compose.yml

```
nginx:
build: "."
container_name: "nginx"
ports:
- "80:80"
- "443:443"
volumes:
- /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/
command: /sbin/init
```

■Dockerfile

```
# CentOS 7.2のイメージ
FROM centos:centos7

MAINTAINER nginx

# システムアップデートとリポジトリ追加
RUN yum -y install epel-release;

# nginx他インストール
RUN yum -y install nginx

# timezone変更
RUN cp -p /usr/share/zoneinfo/Japan /etc/localtime

# nginx.confgのコピー
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN systemctl start nginx
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dockerfileはコンテナ(プロセス)を起動するためのものではありません。
コンテナイメージを作成するためのものです。
コンテナイメージとは、ざっくり言ってファイル群とDockerのメタ情報をまとめたもので、コンテナを起動する起点です。
要するに、コンテナで実行したいプロセスに必要なファイル群を集めるのがDockerfileの主な役目です。

つまり、`RUN systemctl start nginx`のように、プロセスの起動を目的としたコマンドをDockerfileに書いても意味がありません。
Dockerfileで作ったコンテナイメージを`docker-compose up`したときに`systemctl start nginx`を実行したいのであれば、docker-compose.ymlに[command設定](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/command)を書くか、Dockerfileに[CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/cmd)か[ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/entrypoint)を指定しておけばいいはずです。

また、コンテナ内ではsystemdが起動するわけではないので、そもそも`systemctl`でnginxを起動するのも間違っています。
nginxを直接起動するか、[dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init)のようなツールを使うべきです。

Comment: ご丁寧にご回答頂きありがとうございます。

Comment: すみません。途中で送信してしまいました。
ご丁寧にご回答頂きありがとうございます。
基本的な概念が分かっていなかったようでお恥ずかしい限りです。

CMDの話がでたので、もしよろしければもう一点だけ教えてください。
CMDは一つのコマンドしか実行できないはずです。
つまり、'systemctl start nginx'をdocker-compose.ymlもしくはDockerfileに記載すると'command: /sbin/init'が上書きされてしまい、実行されません。
複数コマンドを実行したい場合にはどのような記載が正しいのでしょうか。

Comment: Dockerのコンテナは、1コンテナ1プロセスを起動するように設計されています。複数プロセスを起動する必要があるとしたら、コンテナの使い方を見直した方がよいです。すくなくともnginxのコンテナを起動したいのであれば、nginxプロセスだけを起動すべきな気がします。(nginxに詳しくないのであれですが。) 単に複数コマンドを実行したいのであれば、`&&`でつないでやればできるはずです。

Comment: なるほど。ご丁寧にありがとうございました。